# Disable terminal escape sequences in node.js output

Tags: windows, node.js, ansi-escape

I'm using Karma on node.js to run tests as part of a build script. When running the command standalone, it looks like this:

[image]

However, when run as part of the build job it becomes this:

```
TestJs:
  node node_modules\karma\bin\karma start lib\Tests.conf.js
  ←[33mWARN [karma]: ←[39mPort 19876 in use
  ←[32mINFO [karma]: ←[39mKarma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:19877/
  ←[32mINFO [launcher]: ←[39mStarting browser PhantomJS
  ←[32mINFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8)]: ←[39mConnected on socket tw-cSawB8PRCSVL-QYsr with id 81276065
```

which gets a bit hard to read. Apparently Node itself has some sort of support for translating ANSI escape sequences into the Windows console APIs, but this gets lost when redirecting or capturing output (the file written when doing a shell redirect contains the escape sequences as well).

Is there any way to suppress the colours? `node --help` mentions `$Env:NODE_DISABLE_COLORS`, however, that seems to be only for the REPL and doesn't do anything for me for running a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a line in the Karma config:

```
// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,
```

which I just forgot to change.